# Adding new field to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, dto

I am new to c# and .net api. I am doing a login method where if a user is found in database, it will return the user.The user object is likethis,

```
{ email: user@email.com, password: password, name: User Name, }
```

First thing, I want to remove the password from the return object, second I want to add the JWT token to the return object. Here is my code:

```
    public object LoginCurrentUser(User user) {
        var result = AuthenticateUser(user);

        if (result != null)
        {
            var token = Generate(user);

       //I want to create new variable here that removes the password and adds the token to the field.

            return result;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: To me it looks like a `Dictionary<string, string>` or `Dictionary<object, object>` `KeyValuePairs`. So why not cast it into a `Dictionary` and then you can use `TryGetValue()` or `Remove()` to get or remove the password and then use `Add()` to add the `JWT`. You can also use [Overview of ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: you can add `[JsonIgnore]` attribute for the fields you don't want to be returned in the response and you can add `[NotMapped]` attribute for the fields that are not mapped from the database and initialize them in the response builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty straight forward.

```
if (result != null)
{
    var token = Generate(user);

    var response = new {
        Email = result.Email,
        Name = result.Name,
        Token = token
    };

    return response;
}
```

Alternatively, You can create a [DTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) class for the response and return its object.